# Regex to split the first from a "/token1/token2/token3"

Tags: java, regex, guava

I'm pretty rusty with regex, but I have the requirement to extract the first token of the following string:

Input: `/token1/token2/token3`

Required output: `/token1`

I have tried:

```
List<String> connectorPath = Splitter.on("^[/\\w+]+")
                    .trimResults()
                    .splitToList(actionPath);
```

Doesn't work for me, any ideas?

Comment: Why not just match on `^/\\w+` instead of split?

Comment: Yes, Guava Splitter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on the `/` that is not at the string start using the `(?!^)/` regex:

```java
String[] res = "/token1/token2/token3".split("(?!^)/");
System.out.println(res[0]); // => /token1
```

See the [Java code demo](https://ideone.com/vTWVvJ) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TzZhFO/1).

- `(?!^)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location not at the start of string
- `/` - a `/` char.

Using Guava:

```java
Splitter splitter = Splitter.onPattern("(?!^)/").trimResults();
Iterable<String> iterable = splitter.split(actionPath);
String first = Iterables.getFirst(iterable, "");
```

Comment: @Shvalb `Splitter.onPattern("(?!^)/").omitEmptyStrings().splitToList(actionPath)`?

Comment: how about if I would like the output to look like this:
```["/token1","/token2", "/token3", ..]```. using Guava Splitter.

Comment: @Shvalb You can use `(?!^)(?=/)` regex for that.

Comment: for `"token1/token2"` it gives `["token1", "/token2"] `. I would expect it to do `["/token2"]`, what do you think?

Comment: @Shvalb Tricky. Try `"(?:^[^/]+)?(?!^)(?=/)"`. Actually, since empty items are removed, use `"(?:^[^/]+)?(?=/)"`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of split, you can match

```
^/\\w+
```

Or if the string has 3 parts, use a capture group for the first part.

```
^(/\\w+)/\\w+/\\w+$
```

Java example

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^/\\w+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("/token1/token2/token3");

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

Output

```
/token1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating it.

Try the following regular expression: `^(\/\w+)(.+)$`

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PathSplitter {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      String input = "/token1/token2/token3";
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\/\\w+)(.+)$");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
      if (matcher.find()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //  /token1
         System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); //  /token2/token3
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
      }
   }
}
```